# jQuery hide div on click and show another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am playing around with jQuery and I am trying to show a hidden div on click of the parent div. Once clicked the parent div would then hides some span tags inside it and display the p tag from the hidden div. This bit I can get to work as per the below fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper').click(function() {
    $('.hidden-text').toggle();
    $('.test-span').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 5px solid #718373;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <span class="test-span">some text</span>
  <span class="test-span">some more text</span>
  <div class="hidden-text">
    <p>A half an hour lesson for one person will include 25 clays and 25 cartridges</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that I then want 'on click' again to reverse the above but I'm just not to sure how to go about it. I'm still learning my way around jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by calling `toggle()` on both elements at the same time. As they start in opposite states, then the toggle will simply switch which one of them is visible at any given time. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper').click(function() {
    $('.hidden-text, .test-span').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 5px solid #718373;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <span class="test-span">some text</span>
  <span class="test-span">some more text</span>
  <div class="hidden-text">
    <p>A half an hour lesson for one person will include 25 clays and 25 cartridges</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A little late, but no problem, glad to help! :)